# Reemplazar varios caracteres al mismo tiempo de un texto en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, script, jupyter, str-replace

Yo estoy tratando de escribir un código en Python que me reemplace las letras S,E,O,G por E, S, H y C respectivamente, es decir,  que a S la reemplace por E a la E la reemplace por S y así sucesivamente, para esto he escrito el siguiente código:

```
texto="SSEEHDDOGBSW"
alfabeto="SEOG"
clave="ESHC"
for i in range(len(clave)):
    texto_cifrado=texto.replace(alfabeto[i],clave[i])
print(texto_cifrado)
```

El problema es que obtengo que texto_cifrado=SSEEHDDOCBSW
Y debería obtener en su lugar EESSHDDHCBEW

Qué puedo hacer para remediar el problema? Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Tienes un problema, y es que en cada iteración del bucle vuelves a asignar lo que había en la variable `texto_cifrado`, al hacer:

```
for i in range(len(clave)):
    texto_cifrado=texto.replace(alfabeto[i],clave[i])
```

y cada vez que reasignas pierdes lo que había antes en ella, por lo que al final obtienes el resultado sólo de la última iteración, en la que cambias "C" por "G".

Una idea que se te podría ocurrir es usar la propia variable `texto`, en lugar de `texto_cifrado`, así:

```
for i in range(len(clave)):
    texto = texto.replace(alfabeto[i],clave[i])
```

de este modo, en cada iteración del bucle actúas sobre la misma variable `texto`, y por tanto en cada iteración cambias una nueva letra sobre el resultado de la iteración anterior. Por desgracia esto tampoco funcionará. El resultado es:

```
SSSSHDDHCBSW
```

¿Ves qué ha pasado? En la primera iteración del bucle se cambian las S por E, y sale `EEEEHDDOGBEW`, pero en la siguiente se cambian las E por S, quedando `SSSSHDDOGBSW`, lo que ya está mal. EL problema es que una vez hemos cambiado las S por E, no es posible distinguir qué E ya estaba ahi del texto original (y esas son las que habría que cambiar por S) y cuáles son resultado de la sustitución anterior (que no habría que cambiarlas).

El enfoque de usar `replace()` por tanto está mal.

### Otro enfoque

Lo que habría que hacer sería iterar sobre las letras del `texto`, para ir generando un texto cifrado por acumulación de letras. Para cada letra del texto original, añadimos una nueva letra al texto cifrado, usando como "tabla de traducción" la conversión "S" -> "E", "E" -> "S", "O" -> "H" y "G" -> "C".

Esta tabla puede estar almacenada en dos cadenas separadas, tal como tú las tienes, pero eso obligará a hacer otro bucle dentro del bucle, para buscar la letra en una de las cadenas y así hacerla corresponder con la otra. Más eficiente será tener la tabla de traducción en un diccionario, así:

```
cifra = {
 'S': 'E',
 'E': 'S',
 'O': 'H',
 'G': 'C'
}
```

Si no quieres tener que hacer "a mano" el diccionario, puedes crearlo con esta expresión (pero esto puede considerarse "python avanzado"):

```
cifra = { letra: cifrada for letra, cifrada in zip(alfabeto, clave) }
```

Con un diccionario como este, el cifrado consistirá simplemente en iterar sobre cada letra del texto original, buscando esa letra en el diccionario y cambiándola por el valor sacado del diccionario. Esto puede hacerse de forma más o menos eficiente según tus conocimientos.

Un enfoque sencillo pero poco eficiente es ir concatenando letras al mensaje cifrado:

```
texto_cifrado = ""  # Empieza vacio
for letra in texto:
   if letra in cifra:
      texto_cifrado += cifra[letra]
   else:
      texto_cifrado += letra     # Si no está en la cifra, se pasa sin cambiar
```

La concatenación de cadenas no es tan eficiente en Python como el crecimiento de listas, por lo que otro enfoque sería crear una lista (de letras) para el texto cifrado. Por otro lado, para ahorrar el `if` que mira si la letra está o no en el diccionario, podemos usar `cifra.get(letra, letra)`. El método `get()` busca una clave en el diccionario y si la encuentra devuelve su valor. Si no la encuentra por defecto devuelve `None`, pero si le pasas un segundo parámetro devuelve ese. Así que en nuestro caso pasamos `letra` y si no la encuentra, que devuelva la misma `letra`.

```
texto_cifrado = [] # Ahora es una lista
for letra in texto:
   texto_cifrado.append(cifra.get(letra, letra))
# Podemos volver a convertir la lista en cadena
texto_cifrado = "".join(texto_cifrado)
```

## Versión avanzada

Usando expresiones generadoras podemos reducirlo todo a una línea:

```
texto_cifrado = "".join(cifra.get(letra, letra) for letra in texto)
```

Answer (score 0):

Para casos como este existe el método `translate()`:

```
texto="SSEEHDDOGBSW"
alfabeto="SEOG"
clave="ESHC"

conversion = str.maketrans(alfabeto, clave)
print(texto.translate(conversion))
```

El método `maketrans()` devuelve correlación de caracteres que puede utilizar el método `translate()`.

En este caso concreto `maketrans()` devolvería `{83: 69, 69: 83, 79: 72, 71: 67}` (Código ASCII)

Y translate lo transformaria a `EESSHDDHCBEW`